# How to drop rows with nan cell in dask dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, dask

I have a dask dataframe in which I want to delete all the rows which have an NAN value in the "selling_price" column

```
image_features_df.head(3)
   feat1   feat2   feat3  ...  feat25087    feat25088   fid   selling_price
0   0.0    0.0     0.0    ...   0.0          0.0         2       269.00
1   0.2    0.0     0.8    ...   0.0          0.3         22      NAN    
2   0.5    0.0     0.4    ...   0.0          0.1         70      NAN
```

The above table shows a view of my dataframe.

I want the output to be a dask dataframe without any NAN cells in my "selling_price" column.

Expected Output:

```
image_features_df.head(3)
   feat1   feat2   feat3  ...  feat25087    feat25088   fid   selling_price
0   0.0    0.0     0.0    ...   0.0          0.0         2       269.00
4   0.3    0.1     0.0    ...   0.0          0.3         26      1720.00    
6   0.8    0.0     0.0    ...   0.0          0.1         50      18145.25
```

Comment: Can you share the expected output ?

Comment: Shared the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following, this will remove line if NaN is found in column selling_price.

```
df.dropna(subset=['selling_price'])
```